# jquery plugin this.each in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to write a small jquery plugin. In the past i used javascript mainly. 
I don`t understand the this.each function. First of all i write a new method for $.fn. In this method i want to get the offset().top of all elements.

```
$.fn.jquerynParalFade = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).offset().top);
  });
}
```

This works fine for me. But if i resize the screen (for example on turning my device) i want to get the new position of all elements. For this i added a function which could run on resize.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  resize();
});
```

Now I have the problem that i can´t use this.each() inside of the function. Instead I use `$(this).each`. But if i do the console tells me that `offset()` isn't a function of `$(this)`.

This is what that code looks like:

```
function resize(){
  $(this).each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).offset().top);
  });
}
```

So how i use this.each in a function of a jquery plugin?

Comment: What should `$(this)` be? Because when you call `resize()` you aren't setting `this` to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to bind the context of what `this` is to your function for the resize to work properly:

```
var myResize = resize.bind(this)
myResize() // now it should work
```

Another way is to pass the context:

```
function resize (context) {
  context.each( ... )
}

$(window).resize(function () { resize(this) })
```

Some concepts to read about:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: i realy try to understand it! I gues i understand the second one. but it doesn't works. the console tells me that context.each isn´t a function. But doesnt matter because i believe the first one is smarter. but i don´t understand the bind method. do i bind this to my resize function? if yes why i save the bind on a variable? And do you call the new variable in the next line? Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: btw the console tells me that inside of the resize function this is something like : Window → file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/parallax/index.html. Is this correktly? Because i expected an object?!

Comment: ok after reading the urls i got it. They was very helpful. Thank you a lot!